# Android sdk & timers (Chronometer vs. Thread)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer

There are few built in ways to invoke a timer using the Android stack,
A good example is the [Chronometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html).

I would like to integrate piece of code (A thread)that implements timer using the Thread.sleep() method

I plan to have a Service tat invoke this thread and communicate with it.

Are there any disadvantages of using the sleep() method over Chronometer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends if it's sensitive to lifecycle. If your activity or service will be paused your timer will be stopped. Look into [Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). There are plenty of examples on this site about.